# ASP.NET Page_Load fires twice with different values of IsPostback (ONLY ON GOOGLE CHROME)

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have an asp.net web application that has been behaving strangely for some time now.
When I click any button, the Page_Load method of the various pages always enters 2 times.
The first time the IsPostback parameter has the correct value, and the second it doesn't.

I read that applications that passes more times in Page_Load could have href or src empty but in my page I can't find anything.

one page is https://almarea.it/login

The code of the button in aspx page  is

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkBtnLogin" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" OnClick="lnkBtnLogin_Click" Text="LOGIN"></asp:LinkButton>
```

The code in the code behind is quite long but if I try to remove all that code and let it empty the problem is still there.

```
protected void lnkBtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

So the problem is not here.

I checked for empty src and empty href but I didn't find anything.

**EDIT** ---------------------------------------------------------------
While I have no idea of where to look for this error, I create a new project asp net web form, a new master page and a new page, completely blank with only one Button (changed from LinkButton to Button)

I have the same error, Page_Load called twice entering the page the first time (with IsPostback false)
When I click the button the method lnkBtnLogin_Click fires once and Page_Load fires twice, one time with IsPostback=true and secont time with IsPostBack=false.

Since the project is new, I assume that is a visual studio/application property/web config error.

Can someone try to do a new project and tells me if has the same error?

GITHUB
I create a github project with the empty solution to let you check my problem

[GITHUB LINK](https://github.com/ferrarinim/IsPostbackError/tree/master/ErrorCase)

**EDIT** ---------------------------------------------------------------

THIS HAPPENS ONLY WITH GOOGLE CHROME BROWSER

Comment: Golly gee, I don't have nor use chrome from google. However, I just installed chrome, and cloned your repo. I don't get nor see 2 clicks when I click on that button in the logon.aspx page.  See my edit #2 below - I have a screen cap/gif of me clicking on the button using chrome - I only get one click and page load when I click on that button.

Comment: I think the problem could be One of my google Chrome extension, opening a browser session without estensions I don’t have the issue. Could it be possible?

Comment: Hum, that's still a strange behavour. But, yes, it is likly that some browser setting or extension is the issue here. So, I tested with FireFox, Edge (which is now chrome based), and then with Google chrome. For all 3 cases, I don't see nor get a "double" click. I suppose it could be a mouse that is clicking two times, but as you note, with other browsers, the issue does not show.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a master + child page? In that case, both master page load, and child page load triggers.

It also possible that your button code does a response.redirect back to the same page, which of course would also cause a double page load. The other possible is use of postback URL in the button. In that case, you don't want to have a event stub for that button, so either remove postbackURL from the button, or remove the event stub in code behind - don't have both.

You could post just the button markup, and then say the button event code stub.

The other possible is some JavaScript code that posts-back to the same page.

## Edit: Also check for empty hrefs on page

There also suggesting that hrefs='' or url('') in css can cause this.

So, change any blank href to href="#" in place of "", and same goes for anything on the page with url('') to url('#') if being used in css.

## Edit2: Testing with chrome, and sample repo

Hum, I just tested the sample.

With chrome, I launch, and get this:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply, Yes, I'm using master + child page.  I updated my question

Answer (score -1):

Check your browser dev tools (the network tab) and look at what is initiating the second request.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I updated my question and I tryied to watch network tab in browser dev tools but I can't understand where is the problem.

Comment: You could try changing that link button to a simple asp.net button (not sure why it is a link button anyway???). the other thing that has come up is textbox or other controls on the page with a autopostback = true. So, look for/check to see if controls on the page have a auto-post back setting.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal changed from LinkButton to Button and the error is still the same, I edited my question.

Comment: Did you check the network tools of the browser, does it do two requests?